# Automatically Save Multiple API Responses as XML Files from a Collection Run in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I am new to Postman and I am trying to save multiple responses to a an API call that I am running against different values and I wanted to know if there is a way to automatically save each response locally as an XML file instead of me having to manually save every response.

Right now I am just going to every response, manually copying it to a text editor, and saving it but that's annoying when you have hundreds of responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Newman`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#newmanrunevents) JavaScript library.

[Using Newman as a Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#using-newman-as-a-library) for running Postman collection by `node` + [newman run events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#newmanrunevents) for response saving to file.

[image]

##### Demo Steps

[image]

Demo using [`simple calculator`](http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx) by SOAP API.
I will call four operation (+,/, *, -)

SOAP URL

```
http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx
```

In header, the `Content-Type` should be `text/xml; charset=utf-8`
(not application/xml)

[image]

In Body of POST call for an addition

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <intA>14</intA>
            <intB>7</intB>
        </Add>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

[image]

##### Step 1

Make Postman collection with REST API call

[image]

##### Step 2

Export collection
collection file name

```
simple-calculator.postman_collection.json
```

This is full collection

```json
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "2700a5f9-223a-4641-9d97-0db0c88465fd",
        "name": "simple-calculator",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json",
        "_exporter_id": "1826150"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "addition",
            "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                "disabledSystemHeaders": {
                    "content-type": true
                }
            },
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "raw": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\r\n    <soap:Body>\r\n        <Add xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\r\n            <intA>14</intA>\r\n            <intB>7</intB>\r\n        </Add>\r\n    </soap:Body>\r\n</soap:Envelope>",
                    "options": {
                        "raw": {
                            "language": "xml"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "www",
                        "dneonline",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "calculator.asmx"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "division",
            "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                "disabledSystemHeaders": {
                    "content-type": true
                }
            },
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "raw": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\r\n    <soap:Body>\r\n        <Divide xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\r\n            <intA>14</intA>\r\n            <intB>7</intB>\r\n        </Divide>\r\n    </soap:Body>\r\n</soap:Envelope>",
                    "options": {
                        "raw": {
                            "language": "xml"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "www",
                        "dneonline",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "calculator.asmx"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "multiplication",
            "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                "disabledSystemHeaders": {
                    "content-type": true
                }
            },
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "raw": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\r\n    <soap:Body>\r\n        <Multiply xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\r\n            <intA>14</intA>\r\n            <intB>7</intB>\r\n        </Multiply>\r\n    </soap:Body>\r\n</soap:Envelope>",
                    "options": {
                        "raw": {
                            "language": "xml"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "www",
                        "dneonline",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "calculator.asmx"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "subraction",
            "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                "disabledSystemHeaders": {
                    "content-type": true
                }
            },
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "raw": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\r\n    <soap:Body>\r\n        <Subtract xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\r\n            <intA>14</intA>\r\n            <intB>7</intB>\r\n        </Subtract>\r\n    </soap:Body>\r\n</soap:Envelope>",
                    "options": {
                        "raw": {
                            "language": "xml"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "www",
                        "dneonline",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "calculator.asmx"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ]
}
```

##### Step 3

create write file(.js)

This full demo code

Save `resultSaveFile.js`

```js
const newman = require('newman'); // require newman in your project
const fs = require('fs');

// call newman.run to pass `options` object and wait for callback
newman.run({
    collection: require('./simple-calculator.postman_collection.json'),
    reporters: 'cli'
}).on('request', (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    const fileName = `${data.item.name}.XML`;
    fs.writeFile(fileName, data.response.stream.toString(), function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    })
})
```

##### Step 4

Install dependency

```
npm install newman fs
```

##### Step 5

```
node resultSaveFile.js
```

##### Result

Four files will be save
(addition.XML, division.XML, mutiplication.XML and subtraction.XML)

In `addition.XML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <AddResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <AddResult>21</AddResult>
        </AddResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

[image]