# Getting SOAP to run in Postman. Request succeeds but output is not what I expected

Tags: xml, soap, postman

I've been struggling with this Archer SOAP request to work. I've been playing around with it and I am finally not getting bad request errors, it looks like its succeeding, but I'm not sure how to handle the output or what to do next.

Here is what it looks like:

Headers
[image]

Body
[image]

Output
[image]

I am running this to attempt to create a session with the API and use that session token in another POST to get the data I need from ARcher.

Before I was getting errors, I kept playing with the POST URL. If I had to guess, it could be something with the formatting, but I'm not sure on what it could be. I was given a list of inputs from my Archer dev:
[image]
And as seen in the pictures, I've copied what I was given into Postman but it's just not making sense to me in what should be returning.

Any thoughts here or things to try? I'd appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: https://www.archerirm.community/t5/archer-api-users/soap-request-endpoint/td-p/681807

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a login request body to the wrong url. There is no Archer service called searchByReport.asmx. The login method is contained in the general.asmx service.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.

In input, `headers` tab.

Uncheck the `Content-Type: application/xml`

Check and add value `Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8`

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bench Vue. I must have cut off the top of my headers screenshot. The first Content-Type is unchecked, this happens automatically when I inserted the 2nd Content-Type. The 2nd one has the value listed in the last screenshot: `application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action=http://archer-tech.com/webservices/SearchRecordsByReport`. When I removed everything after the UTF-8, there is no change in the output.

Comment: I can't test your SOAP URL but I found that was similar situation when I call SOAP calculator. It addressed me in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76971768/automatically-save-multiple-api-responses-as-xml-files-from-a-collection-run-in/76973383#76973383). Did you try this?
`text/xml;charset=UTF-8;action=http://archer-tech.com/webservices/SearchRecordsByReport`

Comment: That means uncheck(not using auto added the default), check(new added by manual) the `Content-Type`, see the upper image which I attached my answer.

Comment: Same thing - the return message doesn't change when I change the Content-Type to `text/xml;charset=UTF-8;action=http://archer-tech.com/webservices/SearchRecordsByReport`

Comment: OK, my answer not address your case, sorry.

Comment: No worries, thanks for attempting to help!